# By how much will reducing txpower for a new Dell laptop running Linux affect wifi performance?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

I want to get txpower as low as possible.

Will significant reduction be possible with the new wifi management software?

One of the reasons I’m still on a 13 year old Macbook is that the wifi signal is pretty weak.

I recently found out that I can change the strength of a new machine’s card by using the txpower function in Linux, but I’m worried that it won’t work: That by reducing the txpower the wifi will just disconnect, and I’ll be left not being able to use the machine well.

The signal from wifi and also radio signals give me a headache pretty easily, and though it may “just be in my head” it’s pretty rough to deal with. Thanks!

Comment: WiFi performance is dependent on so many factors unique to your hardware and environment, there is no way for anyone to give an accurate answer.  You will have to do your own testing to find out.

Comment: Drop the WIFI connection and use an ethernet cable instead.

Comment: Throwing science out the window, I had an acquaintance who had issues with WIFI, and they spent a stupid amount of money on a passive device to absorb WIFI signals from anywhere in the same room.   I looked into this, and discovered the "magic" was a copper rod.    Go to your local hardware or plumbing store, and get yourself a piece of copper tubing or pipe.  Cut it as close to 125mm as you can and mount it so it sits horizontally on a piece of wood.  Leave this device in the room with your computer....

Comment: The manufacturers provided test results from the version of this device they tested at aan reputable lab showing it was effective at absorbing WIFI across the spectrum (ie reducing the signal) without blocking the ability of devices to work - as there was a residual signal.   I can't find the original device, and I've forgotten its name, but if you can do this for under $5 and it will help you sleep at night, its done its job.

Comment: Found the original product.  **PLEASE DO NOT BUY IT - IT IS REALLY WORTH LESS THEN $5.00** - the device was https://www.amazon.com/Synergy-Science-Qi-Shield-Protection/dp/B08JD3ZNZ9 - I confirm I am only advising you based on the last sentence of your post.  Again, I would never advocate purchasing something like this for anything more then pocket change.  If making your own works for you for a couple of dollars, great.

Comment: I purchased something like this a few years ago, and of course it made no difference. I sent it back as it had an unconditional guarantee. Most people aren't affected to the point that they can feel it themselves, so they are easily duped I guess? Yes, I'm still looking for some data on how low the txpower can be in a typical home or office setting and still function with the current card and power management for a new Dell laptop. I'm on a 2008 Al body macbook whose fields are tolerable for me, and it really is time to replace it. Thanks!!